# Парсер S-выражений

Tags: haskell

Написал урезанный парсер S-выражений, вот код:

```
data Val = Int Integer
           | Float Double
           | String String
           | Symbol String
           | List [Val] deriving (Show)
-- blah blah blah
tList = do char '('
           list <- sepBy (tList <|> tAtom) (many $ char ' ')
           char ')'
           return $ List list
           <?> "list"
```

Вот такие выражения он парсит нормально:

```
(+ 2 (- 4 2))
```

Но если расставить табы, то он не работает:

```
(define (fac n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (fac (- n 1)))
    )
)
```

> unexpected ")".
>
> expecting " ", list or atomic expression

Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Вот как я решил проблему:
http://pastebin.com/Txy40mXm

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно потому что пробел не равен концу строки или табу:

```
list <- sepBy (tList <|> tAtom) (many $ char ' ')
```

У меня нет под рукой Haskell с Parsec, но наверное такое:

```
list <- sepBy (tList <|> tAtom) (many $ (char ' ' <|> char '\t' <|> char '\n'))
```

должно прокатить.

Comment: Нет, все равно не работает
(define f
 (+ 2 2)
)


(line 3, column 1):
unexpected "}"
expecting " ", "\t", "\n", block or atomic expression

Comment: А не могли бы вы привести весь код? Это конечно увлекательно, вычислять ошибку, не видя текста, вслепую, но...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9ZHVtTAs

Comment: sepBy захватывает пробелы перед ")". Используйте endBy. Кстати, там есть парсер space (который один из `" \v\f\t\r\n"`

Comment: >Используйте endBy
Каким образом? Пример можно?

Comment: Вместо sepBy

    tList = do 
       char '('
       block <- endBy (tList <|> tAtom) (many $ char ' ')

Comment: И все равно не работает:

>unexpected ")"
>expecting " ", list or atomic expression

Comment: Вот три здешних примера.

     (+ 2 (- 4 2))
     [List [Symbol "+",Int 2,List [Symbol "-",Int 4,Int 2]]]
     (define (fac n)
         (if (= n 0)
           1
            (* n (fac (- n 1)))
         )
     )
     [List [Symbol "define",List [Symbol "fac",Symbol "n"],Symbol "\n",List [Symbol "if",List [Symbol "=",Symbol "n",Int 0],Symbol "\n",Int 1,Symbol "\n",List [Symbol "*",Symbol "n",List [Symbol "fac",List [Symbol "-",Symbol "n",Int 1]]],Symbol "\n"],Symbol "\n"]]
    (define f
         (+ 2 2)
    )
     [List [Symbol "define",Symbol "f\n",List [Symbol "+",Int 2,Int 2],Symbol "\n"]]

Comment: И мне нравится `Symbol "\n"`